# Edge - Audio tag partial response 206

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, html5-audio

In edge browser audio tag shows only the first audio chunk (Partial response -206) duration. But chrome and firefox browsers it works fine

**Request headers**

Range: bytes=0-

**Response headers:**

accept-ranges: bytes

cache-control: no-cache

content-length: 157648

content-range: bytes 0-157647/15764714

content-type: audio/mpeg

Anyone please let me know how to handle range request in edge browser

Comment: I've made a sample on my side, but I could not reproduce your issue. Here is my runnig result:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTdEL.jpg 

I do not see the 206 status from my result.Could you describe your working steps in detail and share your testing code? Maybe this will be easier to reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for looking into my issue, Instead of giving direct file URL to audio tag, am using web service in src field, which will give partial data of the audio file. code is here: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dev-ppl/code-stack/master/partial-content)